Subrepresentations of the $\text{SL}_n(k)$-representation $\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$
$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL} \newcommand{\gl}{\mathfrak{gl}} \newcommand{\sl}{\mathfrak{sl}}$One of my graduate students asked me for a reference for the following fact.  Let $k$ be a general field (she's particularly interested in $k = \mathbb{F}_2$) and let $n \geq 2$.  Consider the representation $\gl_n(k)$ of $\SL_n(k)$.  Let $V$ be a nonzero proper subrepresentation of $\gl_n(k)$.  Then $V$ is either

the $1$-dimensional line of scalar matrices; or
the subspace $\sl_n(k)$ of trace-$0$ matrices.

I didn't know one off the top of my head.  Can anyone provide such a reference?
(thanks to YCor for cleaning up my original statement)

There a characteristic-free statement: for every field $K$, for the representation of $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$, $n\ge 2$ on $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$, the nontrivial proper subspaces are the 1-dimensional line $\mathfrak{i}_n(K)$ of scalar matrices and the hyperplane $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ of trace-zero matrices. (The characteristic appears when we observe that $\mathfrak{i}_n(K)\subset \mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ iff $n1_K=0$.)

@YCor: That’s a nice observation, and is clearly the correct statement to be looking for here.  Do you know a reference for it?

(actually, I'm going to edit the question to ask for the more general statement)

I'll bet it's in Liebeck and Seitz's papers on classical groups. Also, just to be clear, the representation is the restriction of the adjoint representation, right?

@LSpice: That’s right, it’s the restriction of the adjoint representation of GL.  I’ll take a look at Liebeck and Seitz, thanks!

Ah, here's what I was thinking of: Proposition 1.10 of Liebeck and Seitz - On the subgroup structure of exceptional groups says that the composition series of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, hence of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, over an algebraically closed field is what we expect.  Then a bit of cleaning up—I think just showing that $\operatorname{diag}(1, 0, \dotsc, 0)$ generates $\mathfrak{gl}_n(V)$—should do the job; details omitted since this is (1) overpowered and (2) only over an algebraically closed field anyway.

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\newcommand\gl{\mathfrak{gl}}\newcommand\sl{\mathfrak{sl}}\newcommand\z{\mathfrak z}\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}\DeclareMathOperator\tr{tr}$Write $\z_n(k)$ for the space of scalar matrices in $\gl_n(k)$.
There is one more possibility, namely $\mathcal I = \z_2(\mathbb F_2) + \mathbb F_2\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ (which equals $\z_2(\mathbb F_2) + [\SL_2(\mathbb F_2), \SL_2(\mathbb F_2)]$) when $n = 2$ and $k = \mathbb F_2$.
The claim in the question, thus amended, is equivalent to the claim that $\sl_n(k)$ or $\sl_n(k)/\z_n(k)$, as appropriate, is irreducible for $n \ge 2$.  Indeed, given the latter claim and a submodule $V$ of $\gl_n(k)$ (still for $n \ge 2$, since $n \le 1$ is obvious), we have one of three possibilities:

$V \cap \sl_n(k)$ is all of $\sl_n(k)$, in which case $V$ contains, hence equals, $\sl_n(k)$; or

$V \cap \sl_n(k)$ is trivial, in which case, for every $X \in V$ and $g \in \SL_n(k)$, we have that $\Ad(g)X - X \in V \cap \sl_n(k)$ equals $0$, so that $V$ is contained in, hence equals, $\z_n(k)$; or

$n = 0$ in $k$ and $V \cap \sl_n(k)$ equals $\z_n(k)$, in which case, for every $X \in V$, we have that $g \mapsto \Ad(g)X - X$ may be viewed as a homomorphism $\SL_n(k) \to k$.  If the homomorphism is trivial, which is automatic when $n > 2$ or $k \ne \mathbb F_2$ (since then $\SL_n(k)$ is its own derived group), then again $V$ equals $\z_n(k)$.  If $n = 2$, $k = \mathbb F_2$, and $V$ is not contained in $\sl_n(k)$, then direct computation shows that the only coset of $\z_2(k)$ affording the unique non-trivial homomorphism $\SL_2(k) \to k$ is $\z_2(k) + \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  In particular, $V$ is contained in $\mathcal I$, hence equals $\mathcal I$ or $\z_2(k)$.


I originally intended to mimic the highest-weight argument of Proposition 1.10 of Liebeck and Seitz - On the subgroup structure of exceptional groups, but I realised that weights for diagonal matrices in $\SL_n(\mathbb F_2)$ don't tell us much.  Fortunately, just the "highest" part is enough.
Write $U$ for the subgroup of $\SL_n(k)$ consisting of matrices that are "upper unitriangular" (upper triangular, with $1$s on the diagonal).
Let $W$ be a non-$0$ submodule of $\sl_n(k)/(\z_n(k) \cap \sl_n(k))$.  By Engel's theorem, the space of $U$-fixed vectors in $W$ is non-$0$.  By direct computation, the $U$-fixed subspace of $\sl_n(k)/(\sl_n(k) \cap \z_n(k))$ is spanned by the matrix with $1$ in the $(1, n)$ position, and $0$ elsewhere.  To ease notation, let's write $E_{1, n}$ for this matrix, with analogous notation $E_{i, j}$ in general.  Then we have shown that the image of $E_{1, n}$ belongs to $W$.
Conjugation by appropriate signed permutation matrices (followed by multiplication by $\pm$) shows that the image of each $E_{i, j}$ with $i \ne j$ also belongs to $W$.  Similarly, the image of $\Ad(1 + E_{n, 1})E_{1, n} = E_{1, 1} - E_{n, n}$ belongs to $W$, so again conjugation by signed permutation matrices shows that the images of all $E_{i, i} - E_{j, j}$ belong to $W$.  Since $\{E_{i, i} - E_{j, j}, E_{i, j} \mathrel: 1 \le i \ne j \le n\}$ spans $\sl_n(k)/(\sl_n(k) \cap \z_n(k))$, we are done.

This is great, thanks!  I had a much more hacked-together proof that only worked for $\mathbb{F}_2$ (and only for $n \geq 3$, which is all my student needed), but it seemed silly to put such a proof into a paper.  I had hoped for a reference, but a citable MO answer is really just as good.

@AndyPutman, re, that sounds interesting.  Would you be willing to post it as an answer?

Your proof is much more efficient.  My proof was basically a brute-force computation starting with a nonzero vector, and your use of Engel's theorem bypasses most of it.  Writing it up in a form my student could use seemed pretty daunting, and I'm glad that now I don't have to!
